# Is it possible to add a folium map into a bokeh dashboard? Essentially, making one of the dashboard widgets a folium map

Tags: python, gis, bokeh, dashboard, folium

The other option is to use bokeh's gmap() function, but is that free to use if the addresses are already geocoded? Using the gmap() function requires a google API key, but I'm not sure about the financial implications ti involves.

```
p = gmap("GOOGLE_API_KEY", map_options, title="Title")
```

EDIT:

I was able to add a folium map into a Bokeh dashboard using the following code. It uses a DIV Bokeh widget and inserts inside that widget an iframe:

```
from bokeh.models import Div

output_file('dashboardWithFoliumMap.html')

mapa = Div(text="<iframe src="r'D:\MapFolder\Maps\myMap.html'" style='min-width:calc(100vw - 26px); height: 500px'><iframe>")

show(mapa)
```

Answer (score 0):

For embedding folium maps in Bokeh Dashboard,

1. Create your interactive Map application using folium library and save it as typical html document. E.g: 'imap.html'
2. Use bokeh's Div as shown above to embed 'imap.html' into your dashboard.